# Normalising units/Replace substrings based on lists using Python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, list, dataframe, replace

I am trying to normalize weight units in a string.

Eg:

```
1.SUCO MARACUJA COM GENGIBRE PCS 300 Millilitre - SUCO MARACUJA COM GENGIBRE PCS 300 ML
2. OVOS CAIPIRAS ANA MARIA BRAGA 10UN           - OVOS CAIPIRAS ANA MARIA BRAGA 10U
3. SUCO MARACUJA MAMAO PCS 300 Gram             - SUCO MARACUJA MAMAO PCS 300 G
4. SUCO ABACAXI COM MACA PCS 300Milli litre     - SUCO ABACAXI COM MACA PCS 300ML
```

The keyword table is :

```
unit = ['Kilo','Kilogram','Gram','Milligram','Millilitre','Milli 
         litre','Dozen','Litre','Un','Und','Unid','Unidad','Unidade','Unidades']

norm_unit = ['KG','KG','G','MG','ML','ML','DZ','L','U','U','U','U','U','U']
```

I tried to take up these lists as a table but am having difficulty in comparing two dataframes or tables in python.

I tried the below code.

```
unit = ['Kilo','Kilogram','Gram','Milligram','Millilitre','Milli 
         litre','Dozen','Litre','Un','Und','Unid','Unidad','Unidade','Unidades']
norm_unit = ['KG','KG','G','MG','ML','ML','DZ','L','U','U','U','U','U','U']

z='SUCO MARACUJA COM GENGIBRE PCS 300 Millilitre'
#for row in mongo_docs:
#z = row['clean_hntproductname']

for x in unit:
    for y in norm_unit:
        if (re.search(r'\s'+x+r'$',z,re.I)):
           # clean_hntproductname = t.lower().replace(x.lower(),y.lower())

              # myquery3 = {  "_id" :  row['_id']}
              # newvalues3 = { "$set": {"clean_hntproductname" : 'clean_hntproductname'} }
              # ds_hnt_prod_data.update_one(myquery3, newvalues3)
```

I'm using Python(Jupyter) with MongoDb(Compass). Fetching data from Mongo and writing back to it.

Comment: Hey @Dhanalakshmi V

Welcome to stackoverflow.

You might wanna clean up your code to help people help you answer your question.

There are lines that are commented out. You can start by removing unnecessary code so that it will be easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you want to:

- Update all the rows in a table which contain the words in the `unit` array, to the ones in `norm_unit`.

(Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with MongoDB or Python.)

What you want is to create a mapping (using a hash) of the words you want to change.

Here's a trivial solution (i.e. not best solution but would probably point you in the right direction.)

```
unit_conversions = {
  'Kilo': 'KG'
  'Kilogram': 'KG',
  'Gram': 'G'
}

# pseudo-code
for each row that you want to update
  item_description = get the value of the string in the column

  for each key in unit_conversion (e.g. 'Kilo')
    see if the item_description contains the key
    if it does, replace it with unit_convertion[key] (e.g. 'KG')
    update the row
```